# Any javascript method for canvas image cover detection?

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-processing, canvas

I'm developing following case.

1. Html canvas created by JS.
2. There are a star image(loaded from png with alpha=0 background) and a diamond image(also loaded from png with alpha=0 background) on canvas.
3. diamond image is moving toward the star image.
4. when diamond image is completely behind the star image, like showing star image only and diamond image is completely behind the star image, alert("Hidden");
5. if more than one pixel of the diamond is shown, alert should not appear.

Since the alpha value of the background of the star is 0, which means star is not a rectangle, it is difficult to detect whether the star image is fully covering the diamond image.

Is there any library or way to detect whether an image is fully covered by other?

Or, does any one know the name of this algorithm so that I can implement in JS?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sorry, but questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Just compare content of canvas with a separate canvas where you draw just the top image. If they contain the same data then only the top image is visible

Comment: @j08691 I changed the title from 'javascript library' to 'javascript method'

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Wouldn't it be slow if there are many images? any faster way?

Comment: There isn't any faster way unless you know the geometry in advance and can do a point-in-path check (or rather check intersection between two paths). You can trace the objects in advance and use those polygons as basis for path check. If that isn't an option you will have to check pixels. You can reduce pixel check load by only checking a part of the object, the part you know must be hidden for it to trigger.

Comment: @JohnDoyle I toyed a little with pixel region check, see if this is useful and if then I can put is an answer: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/BJVZU/

Comment: @Ken : i just improved a little bit your example, by using 32 bits arrays (4 times less tests), and by looping forward (more cache-friendly). It seems faster. http://jsfiddle.net/BJVZU/6/

Comment: @JohnDoyle No problem. I added the example as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For objects with unknown shape we can check if object is behind by using pixel check.

Here is a full example on how to do this:

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/BJVZU/)**

(GameAlchemist provided a [modified version here](http://jsfiddle.net/BJVZU/6/))

```
/// basic allocations
var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'),
    os = document.createElement('canvas'),
    octx = os.getContext('2d'),
    w = os.width = demo.width,
    h = os.height = demo.height,

    /// the images
    urlD = 'http://i.imgur.com/U72xIMZ.png',
    urlS = 'http://i.imgur.com/n5rgo11.png',
    imgD = new Image(),
    imgS = new Image(),
    cnt = 2,

    /// check region (optimized)
    rect = [140, 140, 180, 60];

/// load images and when ready, start show    
imgD.crossOrigin = imgS.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
imgD.onload = imgS.onload = function() {
    cnt--;
    if (cnt === 0) start();
}
imgD.src = urlD;
imgS.src = urlS;
```

The main function checks the pixels within the region defined above. To optimize we can narrow down the search area. If you need to check if image is visible on the other size the region is simply extended to check that area as well.

The function compares an off-screen canvas with just the foremost image drawn against the "live" canvas where both background and foreground are drawn.

If live canvas = off-screen canvas that means the background image is not visible.

```
function start() {

    octx.drawImage(imgS, (w - imgS.width) * 0.5, 20);

    var x = -50,
        buffer1 = octx.getImageData(rect[0], rect[1], rect[2], rect[3]).data,
        len = buffer1.length;

    loop();

    function loop() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.drawImage(imgD, x, 130);
        ctx.drawImage(imgS, (w - imgS.width) * 0.5, 20);

        if (compare() === true) {
            info.innerHTML = 'Object is behind!';
            return;
        }

        x += 2;
        if (x < w) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }

    function compare() {
        var buffer2 = ctx.getImageData(rect[0], rect[1], rect[2], rect[3]).data,
            i = len - 1;

        while(i--) {
            if (buffer1[i] !== buffer2[i]) return false
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```